# R Shiny interactive plotting with exclusion of outliers

Tags: r, shiny

Is it possible to plot at least one or more interactive plots of other parameter(s), for example wt vs. hp or wt vs. cyl, by modifying the [R Shiny interactive example](https://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/plot-interaction-exclude.html). If possible it will be very useful to plot interactive dose response curve plots were the user will have the option to dynamically remove the outlying points and plot the curve fit(s). I am currently testing this possibility. Once successful, will post the answer here. Meanwhile if someone has constructive suggestions to achieve this, please advice.

Comment: Why not just duplicating both the plot and also the observeEvent?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to plot multiple interactive plots as suggested by @HubertL and it worked. I am providing the demo code below that could be useful for someone like me.

```
library(ggplot2)


ui <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(width = 6,
           plotOutput("plot1", height = 350,
                      click = "plot1_click",
                      brush = brushOpts(
                        id = "plot1_brush"
                      )
           ),
           actionButton("exclude_toggle", "Toggle points"),
           actionButton("exclude_reset", "Reset"),
           plotOutput("plot2", height = 350,
                      click = "plot2_click",
                      brush = brushOpts(
                        id = "plot2_brush"
                      )
           ),
           actionButton("exclude_toggle2", "Toggle points2"),
           actionButton("exclude_reset2", "Reset")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  # For storing which rows have been excluded
  vals <- reactiveValues(
    keeprows = rep(TRUE, nrow(mtcars)),
    keeprows1 = rep(TRUE, nrow(mtcars))
  )

  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
    # Plot the kept and excluded points as two separate data sets
    keep    <- mtcars[ vals$keeprows, , drop = FALSE]
    exclude <- mtcars[!vals$keeprows, , drop = FALSE]

    ggplot(keep, aes(wt, mpg)) + geom_point() +
      geom_smooth(method = lm, fullrange = TRUE, color = "black") +
      geom_point(data = exclude, shape = 21, fill = NA, color = "black", alpha = 0.25) 
  })


  output$plot2 <- renderPlot({
    # Plot the kept and excluded points as two separate data sets
    keep    <- mtcars[ vals$keeprows1, , drop = FALSE]
    exclude <- mtcars[!vals$keeprows1, , drop = FALSE]

    ggplot(keep, aes(wt, hp)) + geom_point() +
      geom_smooth(method = lm, fullrange = TRUE, color = "black") +
      geom_point(data = exclude, shape = 21, fill = NA, color = "black", alpha = 0.25) 
  })
  # Toggle points that are clicked on plot 1
  observeEvent(input$plot1_click, {
    res <- nearPoints(mtcars, input$plot1_click, allRows = TRUE)

    vals$keeprows <- xor(vals$keeprows, res$selected_)
  })

  # Toggle points that are brushed, when button is clicked on plot 1
  observeEvent(input$exclude_toggle, {
    res <- brushedPoints(mtcars, input$plot1_brush, allRows = TRUE)
    vals$keeprows <- xor(vals$keeprows, res$selected_)
  })

  # Reset all points for plot 1
  observeEvent(input$exclude_reset, {
    vals$keeprows <- rep(TRUE, nrow(mtcars))
  })

  # Toggle points that are clicked on plot 2
  observeEvent(input$plot2_click, {
    res <- nearPoints(mtcars, input$plot2_click, allRows = TRUE)

    vals$keeprows1 <- xor(vals$keeprows1, res$selected_)
  })

  # Toggle points that are brushed, when button is clicked on plot 2
  observeEvent(input$exclude_toggle2, {
    res <- brushedPoints(mtcars, input$plot2_brush, allRows = TRUE)
    vals$keeprows1 <- xor(vals$keeprows1, res$selected_)
  })

  # Reset all points for plot 2
  observeEvent(input$exclude_reset2, {
    vals$keeprows1 <- rep(TRUE, nrow(mtcars))
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```